# How to Fetch first 10 elements from JSONB Column in postgres

Tags: java, arrays, json, postgresql, unnest

My requirement is to fetch first n elements from jsonb column and display in UI , I'm using Java and angular, as a first step I'm trying to find whether I can found something on DB so that I don't need to write any json parsing logic in java, so my question is to retrieve first n elements from JSONB column from postgres, with limit

I have Json value like this in my DB:

```
{"firstName": "Hello", "lastName": "Hi", "address" : [{"addressLine1": "line1", "street1": "street"},
                                                       {"addresLine2":  "line2","street2": "street2"}                  ]}
```

now I want to get the first n elements, here the elements are : firstName, LastName, AddressLine1, street1, addressLine2, street2 etc..  with limit from 1-10 , 11-20  elements etc.. I googled postgres functions like jsonb_each... and couldn't find anything which is providing limit, is there a way we can do this ?

Here is the query I tried :

```
select jsonb_each(jsonbcolumn) from my_table
```

which gave a all the elements of json into key value pair

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest the array with `jsonb_array_elements()` in a lateral join. Option `with ordinality` can be used to rank the array elements and limit the number of results:

```
select t.*, x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select *
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.jsonbcolumn -> 'address') with ordinality as x(obj, rn)
    order by x.rn
    limit 10
) x
```

Comment: what is rn here, I executed the same query and I'm getting can't extract elements from an object

Comment: @user2108383: `rn` is the *ordinality*, the index of the element inside the array. I fixed the query for the error you are getting.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the edit, but I'm getting only address entries, not the firstanme and lastname